# Problem with adding JavaScript code to similar elements

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to add JavaScript function to similar element but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I also tried modifying JavaScript code by using querySelectorAll and Foreach but it didn't worked, It add the class but when it come to removing class it broke down and console just kept throwing undefined errors.

```js
const containerDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.box.center');
containerDivs.forEach(containerDiv => {
    const leftContainer = containerDiv.querySelector('.left_container');
    const arrow = containerDiv.querySelector('.arr_container');
    const cancel =  containerDiv.querySelector('.cancel');

    arrow.addEventListener("click", ({ target: arrow }) => {
        arrow.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("off")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("off");
            leftContainer.classList.add("active");
        }

    });

    cancel.addEventListener("click", ({ target: cancel }) => {
        cancel.classList.add("active_arr");
        if (leftContainer.classList.contains("active")) {
            leftContainer.classList.remove("active");
            leftContainer.classList.add("off")
        }

    });
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c5346, #203a43, #0f2027);
}

.center{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main{
    height: 100vh;
}

.box{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px; 
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.288);
    border-radius: 23px;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.user_name{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.skill{
    color: rgba(225,225,225,0.555);
}
/*arrow*/
.arr_container .cancel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.arr_container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.arr_container i{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.active_arr{
    transform: translate(80%, 80%);
}
.left_container{
    position: absolute;
    background: #0f2027;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 23px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 20px;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.off{
    transform: translate(-80%,-80%) rotate(90deg);
}
.active{
    transform: translate(0) rotate(0);
}
.left_container p{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem
}
.left_container .skill div{
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(155,155,155);
    border:1px solid rgb(155,155,155);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
}
.left_container .icons{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.left_container .icons i{
    color: #cfcfcf;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all .4s;
}
.left_container .icons i:hover{
    color: #2c5346;
}
.cancel{
        right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: rgb(70,70,70);
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 23px 0 23px 0;
}
.cancel .fas{
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cards.css">
    <title>cards</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main center">
    <div class="box center">
        <img src="2bb723986d0546f2c26bcc27f712f0e0.jpg">
        <div>
            <p class="user_name">Mor Maz</p>
            <p class="skill">Front-end Developer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="arr_container center">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="left_container off">
            <p>Skill</p>
            <div class="skill">
                <div>Html</div>
                <div>Css</div>
                <div>React</div>
                <div>Node Js</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="cancel">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box center">
        <img src="2bb723986d0546f2c26bcc27f712f0e0.jpg">
        <div>
            <p class="user_name">Mor Maz</p>
            <p class="skill">Front-end Developer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="arr_container center">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="left_container off">
            <p>Skill</p>
            <div class="skill">
                <div>Html</div>
                <div>Css</div>
                <div>React</div>
                <div>Node Js</div>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="cancel">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="cards.js"></script>
<!-- <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".arr_container").click(function(){
            $(".left_container").addClass("active")
        })
    })
</script>
<script>
        $(".cancel").click(function(){
            $(".left_container").removeClass("active")
    })
</script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate any kind of help

thank you

Comment: Can you edit the snippet to ensure its output matches the output you're seeing in your local development environment? Looks like you've probably forgotten to include a requisite library or two.

Comment: I just edited and sorry for the messy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classnames and CSS are a mess and you're only adding `active_arr` to `ar` and you're only removing `active_arr` from `cl`. You're also only selecting one `left_container`

You should not reach up to change parents if possible; you should iterate parents, iterate their children, etc

This should get you started.

```
const containerDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.box.center');
containerDivs.forEach(containerDiv => {
    const leftContainer = containerDiv.querySelector('.left_container');
    const arrow = containerDiv.querySelector('.arr_container');
    const cancel =  containerDiv.querySelector('.cancel');

    arrow.addEventListener("click", ({ target: arrow }) => {

    });

    cancel.addEventListener("click", ({ target: cancel }) => {

    });
});
```

Comment: thank u so much, it solved my problem but after hitting the button  2 times it's disappear